# undefined value in haskell

Tags: haskell, undefined

Why I can't use value undefined in haskell ?  I mean that in case:

```
>let t = undefinded
>if t == undefined then "undefined" else "not undefined"
```

It throws `*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`
Can't I use undefined value in such way ?

Comment: Undefined is a bit like an error value. If you evaluate it, it throws an error. It is *not* a data value.

Comment: Haskell allows no null pointer/null value: it was designed to avoid a [billion dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#History).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Prelude's implementation of the `undefined` function:

```
undefined = error "Prelude.undefined"
```

Thus, trying to evaluate `undefined` will raise an exception every time. By comparing `t` to `undefined`, you're enforcing that evaluation.

Note that `undefined` refers to a computation which never completes successfully, not to a not-known value (which is the meaning of `undefined` in JavaScript, for example; do not confuse these two, they are different things).

Comment: Is there some undef value for String, Integer... ?

Comment: @HaskellFun No, if there's a chance that a given function may not to produce a result, you should use the `Maybe` type.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are reasoning by analogy, thinking that "undefined" is the Haskell equivalent of a void pointer or null reference in an OO language. It isn't. In Haskell an undefined value is simply an error waiting to happen.

If you want an optional value (the kind of thing you would use a null reference for in other languages) then you want Maybe. So for instance a Maybe Int is either "Nothing" or "Just 5". So for instance the "lookup" function has type

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

This says that it looks things up in a list of pairs by matching on the key element (type "a") and then returns the second item in the pair (type "b"). Of course it might not find the key, so in that case it returns "Nothing".

```
lookup "foo" [("foo", 1), ("bar, 2)]     gives      Just 1
lookup "wib" [("foo", 1), ("bar, 2)]     gives      Nothing
```

To get the result out of the "Maybe" you use pattern matching:

```
case lookup myKey theTable of
   Just result -> putStrLn $ "Found " ++ show result
   Nothing -> putStrLn "Key not found"
```

You can also use the "maybe" and "fromMaybe" functions in [Data.Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html). If you are absolutely sure that the value is really there then you can also use "fromJust", but you need to be very sure, and even then you probably ought to have an explicit case for Nothing so you can give a useful error message when you turn out to be wrong.

Edit: explanation of why we do it this way

The reason that Haskell doesn't have null references like other languages is that they are inherently ambiguous. When any value might be "Null", you can't be sure whether you ought to be checking for Null or not. So in the "lookup" example above, having the return type "Maybe b" makes it unambiguous, and furthermore if you forget to check then the compiler will tell you. In contrast if "lookup" returned a reference that might be null, how is the caller supposed to know? What happens if one of the arguments to "lookup" was also null. Would that be an error? Having null references means that the only ways to find out are to read the code or hope that it got included in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` is largely just a standard way to generate a “bottom value”. The bottom value (⊥) is the only value that's in *every*<sup>†</sup> type, so you can do

```
Prelude> undefined :: Int
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude> undefined :: Double
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude> undefined :: String
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude> undefined :: IO [Bool]
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Apart from the exception messages, these are equivalent to any “custom” bottom value, like

```
undefined' :: a
undefined' = undefined'  -- this definition creates an infinite loop!
```

This time, I don't get an error message – I have to abort manually:

```
Prelude> undefined' :: Int
^CInterrupted.
```

Actually the Haskell standard guarantees none of this! Any compution that does never terminate with a “proper value” of its specified type is considered to have the value ⊥. Because you can [in general not prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) that a computation will not terminate, it is not possible to ask Haskell if a particular value is ⊥ / `undefined`.

If you want to have values that can explicitly (and testably) have not-values, just wrap the type in a `Maybe`!

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Except in [unboxed types](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.3/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html), but those are an advanced low-level thing mostly used for optimisation.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're looking for is:

```
let t = Nothing :: Maybe String
case t of
  Nothing -> "undefined"
  Just v -> "defined with value: " ++ v
```